# Select a camera and Look Through Selected camera

Tags: maya, mel

I'm was just trying out new things. I thought this would be a lot easier, but I can't find anything relative to what I am looking for, or what I find seems heavily outdated. A lot of results turn out fixes from years ago.

"*lookThru ls -sl*" seems to have been talked about, but that only produced Errors in regards to the used flags.
Other alternative involved having to have the name of the selected camera, but my attempt is to make this universal.

Answer (score 0):

The `lookThru` command needs at least two arguments, first it wants to know the name of a modelingPanel to use and then the name of the camera. While it is easy to find out the name of the current camera with `ls -sl` getting the name of the modelingPanel is a bit more complicated, but there is a way to do it as you can see here: [getting active panel](http://ewertb.mayasound.com/mel/mel.014.php)

Answer (score 0):

To look through the current camera use the following command:

```
select -r camera3;
lookThroughModelPanelClipped camera3 modelPanel4 0.01 100;
```

Or use `lookThru` command with near and far clipping planes:

```
lookThru -nc 0.01 -fc 100 perspView cameraShape3;
```

Answer (score 0):

So after fiddling with this problem I was able to add this command to the marking menu using this.

```
$panel = `getPanel -wf`;

$cam = `ls -sl`;

lookThru $panel $cam;
```

For some silly reason `lookThru` won't accept `ls -sl` as an argument without a flag error so I could only get it to work by assigning `ls -sl` to `cam`.